# Перписать скрипт с Jquery на Vanila

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-events

Имеется скрипт манипуляции атрибутом на `jquery`. Нужно переписать на `js`.
Всё оказалось, куда сложнее чем показалось на первый взгляд. Прошу помочь с этой задачей. Заранее спасибо!

Код:

```
$('.star.rating').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().attr('data-stars', $(this).data('rating'));
});
```

Вот с чем мне уже удалось разобраться...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {    
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.star, .rating'), function(el) {
     el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // мой код..
    })
 })         
})
```

Comment: Обычно просят ванилу на jquery переписать. А тут человек в правильном направлении развивается. Красавчик)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.parentNode.setAttribute("data-stars", this.dataset.rating);
```

Но, вероятно, лучше:

```
this.parentNode.dataset.stars = this.dataset.rating;
```

Кроме того, выборке

```
$('.star.rating')
```

соответствует

```
document.querySelectorAll('.star.rating')
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, вы меня очень выручили!

Comment: @Andriikhmelovskyi На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

Как то так

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {    
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.star, .rating'), function(el) {
     el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      el.parentNode.setAttribute("data-stars", el.getAttribute('data-rating'));
    })
 })         
})
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div class="star" data-rating="1">1</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="rating" data-rating="2">2</div>
  test
</div>
```